# In question/timeline api all votes have the same timestamp... is it intentional?

Tags: discussion

In question/timeline api all votes actions have the same timestamp in creation_date... is it intentional?

Comment: It's to keep people from deducing who made a particular vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vote timestamps are reduced in resolution to a day.  So multiple votes occurring within the same day will all have the same timestamp.

This is intentional.